# How to create a custom listview like iPhone in Android

Tags: iphone, android, android-layout, android-listview

I was designing a custom listview in Android following the online tutorial *[Android Series: Custom ListView items and adapters](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/)* and I created a custom list view like this:

[image]

This is simple and fine. Now I was surfing the web and found this fantastic listview for iPhone:

[image]

How can I create something like this? How has he given a box like interface for each row separating them from background and each other?

Comment: Just to confirm, you'd like a listview to look like that iPhone view? I can't think of a way to do it by default without doing all the drawing yourself (Not sure how to do this). That iPhone view looks like it's just html/css on safari right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try removing the list dividers (`android:divider="@null"` or `android:dividerHeight="0px"`) and using a custom drawable as the background for each row (either a [9patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#NinePatch) or [`ShapeDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape), possibly arranged in a [`StateList`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) so they can have pressed/selected states). Then just also put a margin on the row layout, and your spacing should be taken care of (alternatively, you could use a transparent image as the list's divider with an appropriate height). But be careful about simply aping an iOS style because it looks nice; think about the typical Android user and what they take as interface cues. If you made your Android list look exactly like that screenshot below, I think many Android users wouldn't even realize they could click on those rows, or that they're part of a scrollable list.

Comment: thanks I will try this. I agree that if i make it exactly like that many people will not feel it is click-able. I jut want to make the customlist view look nice. Can you suggest some alternate design which can be used instead of the iphone one??

Comment: Sure -- first off, try Android's light theme instead of the default black; you'll get a lot of mileage out of that alone. I think we did OK with LevelUp's lists (https://market.android.com/details?id=com.scvngr.levelup.app). Twitter's lists are simple but get the job done (https://market.android.com/details?id=com.twitter.android). Really check out a bunch of the popular Twitter apps; they may give you some ideas.

Comment: wow nice thanks I like the scvenger list https://ssl.gstatic.com/android/market/com.scvngr.levelup.app/ss-0-320-480-160-0-4df16e9092afc394f99fb4d813b9489544b23693. How to change the default theme??

How did you put that frame like effect on your images?? is there any batch tool for that??

Comment: On LevelUp, we just overlay the frame .png on the fly (using an image with a transparent center area) on the image in the layout (both images are in a FrameLayout), with the image itself offset from the top/left by the right amount so it fits in the frame (with about 1px bleed on each side that you can't see there). You could probably get a similar effect for pregenerated images with Imagemagick at the command line. More on themes: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 0):

The listview and each item in the listview can have separate backgrounds. So all you need to do is make some [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) files that look like the background of the items and the list itself.

You can set the backgrounds in XML using the `android:src`.

Or at runtime using:

```
setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable."picture name"))
```